# google translate using javascript english to french without select value from dropdown on page load

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I have a site in english and i have to convert all content in to french 
with out select value from google translate drop down on page load 
can you help me.

i create one file for that please help me

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
    google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Why do we use it?

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
```

Comment: Test placing `<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
` before your `googleTranslateElementInit` function declaration

Answer (score 1):

I set french language default

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<style>
#google_translate_element{width:300px;float:right;text-align:right;display:block}
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate { display: none !important;} 
body { top: 0px !important; }
#goog-gt-tt{display: none !important; top: 0px !important; } 
.goog-tooltip skiptranslate{display: none !important; top: 0px !important; } 
.activity-root { display: hide !important;} 
.status-message { display: hide !important;}
.started-activity-container { display: hide !important;}
#google_translate_element{ display: none !important;}
</style>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({  

      includedLanguages: 'fr',
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
    }, 'google_translate_element');

    var lang = 'French';
    var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first'); 
console.log($frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item span.text:contains('+lang+')').click());

  }
</script>








Why do we use it?

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
```